# Javascript how to access elements from am HTML file loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am interested how to access HTML elements from an "outside HTML file" that is embedded into the "core HTML file" (the embedding was done using jQuery) by using javascript (which is part of the "core HTML file").

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/King_Fish/bfzqjw38/5/

Let me provide my example: I have a page saved as `PlantCard.html` (this is the "outside HTML file). Then, in Main.html (the "core HTML file") I have created 4 `div`s and loaded the `PlantCard.html` into them using javascript. This embedding was done in the following manner:

```
var plantCardIds = ["#test", "#test1", "#test2"];

$(document).ready(function() {
 loadPlantCards();
});

function loadPlantCards() {
  var plantInfo = plantCardsInfoLoader();

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < plantInfo.length; i++) {
    $(plantCardIds[i]).load("PlantCard.html");

    /*I want to access and change the elements of "PlantCard.html" HERE!*/
  }
}
```

The function `loadPlantCards()` loads all of the "plant cards" (containers with information about specific plants) by iterating through the `plantCardIds` array (contains the ids of the divs into which the `PlantCard.html` should be loaded into.

However, I want each "plant card" to display different types of information and also a different image of the plant. Therefore, I have to access the elements inside `PlantCard.html`, and here is the problem. So far, I have tried to achieve the desired effect in this manner:

```
function loadPlantCards() {
  console.log("Loading plants...");

  var plantInfo = plantCardsInfoLoader();

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < plantInfo.length; i++) {
    $(plantCardIds[i]).load("PlantCard.html");   
$(plantCardIds[i]).getElementById("plant_name").innerHTML=plantInfo[i].plantName;
  }
}
```

However, when using this line of code (`$(plantCardIds[i]).getElementById("plant_name").innerHTML=plantInfo[i].plantName;`) to access the html inside the respective div which should hold the "plant card", I am greeted with this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getElementById is not a function
```

**Now I would be really glad if someone explained how to access the HTML elements from a page, which is embedded inside a div**.

Comment: `getElementById` is not part of the jQuery API. You could use `$(...).find('#plant_name')` instead.

Comment: Jquery wrapped selectors don't return a DOM node, they return a JQuery Object. A JQuery Object does not have `getElementById`

Comment: You can [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getElementById` is great for this purpose in Vanilla JavaScript, but is not a method in JQuery. To get an element from an HTML file, you should instead run:

```
$(plantCardIds[i]).find('#plant_name')
```

That should work.